# WSO2 MI 4.1.0 zero values for org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView metrics when system is active

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I migrated a project from WSO2 ESB 6.5 to WSO2 MI 4.1.0 and noticed that the monitoring shows zero values for all org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView metrics. As an example:

`HELP org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency_BackEnd Attribute exposed for management org.apache.synapse:name=null,type=null,attribute=1m_Avg_Latency_BackEnd TYPE org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency_BackEnd untyped org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency_BackEnd{Name="nio-http-http",} 0.0 org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency_BackEnd{Name="nio-https-https",} 0.0  HELP org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency Attribute exposed for management org.apache.synapse:name=null,type=null,attribute=1m_Avg_Latency TYPE org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency untyped org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency{Name="nio-http-http",} 0.0 org_apache_synapse_PassthroughLatencyView_1m_Avg_Latency{Name="nio-https-https",} 0.0`

In WSO2 ESB 6.5 everything was displayed. The system works normally and data is transferred successfully, the other metrics are displayed in full, now I collect them through prometheus jmx_exporter, tried to look through JControl the situation is the same. What can be the problem?

I tried to transfer the project to the WSO2 MI 4.2.0 version, everything worked except these metrics, which also had zero values.